# Adding layout elements from another layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get views from another layout modified these and then add them to the current layout. This is what i'm doing.

myLayout looks as follows:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <TextView>
```

And my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
ViewGroup info = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myLayout, layout,false); 
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) info.getChildAt(1);
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) hiddenInfo.getChildAt(1);
TextField tv = vg.getChildAt(1);
...modify tv...
layout.addView(relative);
layout.addView(tv);
```

Though my program always crashes as layout.addView, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If your app crashes you should _always_ post your logcat. Your RelativeLayout `relative` is already a child of `info` and a view can only have **one** parent so trying to use `addView()` will throw an exception. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: what my topic says, i need to add a bunch of views dynamicly and want  to prepare them in xml instead of setting it all in code, tried to do it all in code but that failed as well when adding. Is it that I can not add a relative layout that has elements in it to another view? Because i need to add unknown amounts of <RelativeView><TextView><TextView> to my current layout where i have to modify each textview individually